# Python Dictionary As Function?

Tags: python, dictionary, is-empty

I'm having trouble with a dictionary in Python. I'm creating it as a function return:

```
def dic():
    return {}
```

When I try to update it e.g. in main(), it won't update and stays empty.

```
def main():
    dic().update({'a':1,'b':2})
    print(dic())
```

It returns an empty dictionary. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Every time you run `dic()` it returns a new object.

Answer (score 2):

You use 
`print(dic())`

This will run this function again and return `{}`

So you should use this

```
def dic():
    return {}

b = dic()
b.update({"a":1,"b":2})
print(b)
```

And b is `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}`

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary={}
def dic(dict, terms,values):
    return dict.update({terms:values})

def main():
    dic(dictionary, "a",1)
    dic(dictionary,"b",2)
    print(dictionary)


main()
```